# onConfigurationChanged function does not work

Tags: android

I add below in manifest.xml:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CHANGE_CONFIGURATION"></uses-permission>
android:configChanges="orientation|keyboard"
```

Add manifest.xml:

```
<activity
    android:name="com.example.uidemo.DemoActivity"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:screenOrientation="sensor"
    android:theme="@android:style/Theme.NoTitleBar.Fullscreen"
    android:configChanges="orientation|keyboard"  >
</activity>
```

And add below code on Activity:

```
@Override
public void onConfigurationChanged(Configuration newConfig) {
    super.onConfigurationChanged(newConfig);
    System.out.println("Change!!");
}
```

But when I rotate the screen, it doesn't run in onConfigurationChanged.
It only run onCreate function.
How can I modify it?

Comment: Please post the full entry in AndroidManifest.xml for this activity.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`android:configChanges="orientation|keyboard"` must be placed in the appropriate `<activity>` tag(s). `<uses-permission>` is unnecessary for this

Comment: I place the line in the activity.